# About using java exception breakpoints in intellij idea for ClassNotFoundException

Tags: intellij-idea

When run a project I got below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.coupon.service.FullGiftsActivityService
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
```

then I want to know which class used `FullGiftsActivityService` So I add a `Java Exception Breakpoints` of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, then I found below code step into the breakpoints

```
// findClass:381, URLClassLoader(java.net)
if (result == null) {
    throw new ClassNotFoundException(name); // 381 
}
```

I could understand it because it has an explicitly throw statement, then I resume, it jumps to

```
// loadClass:436, ClassLoader(java.lang)  
    return c;
} // 436
```

[image]

but this time I can not understand, why it jumps to this code ?

In addition both situation have `name` variable and are String type, so for ignoring these noise, I add this condition

[image]

Why it says `cannot resolve symbol 'name'`, so how to only capture this class -- `FullGiftsActivityService`?

Answer (score 0):

You're better off putting a breakpoint in WebappClassLoaderBase on the specified line rather than catching ClassNotFoundException - A lot of the time a ClassNotFoundException will be thrown and caught as part of the webapp's classloading mechanisms, hence all the 'noise' you're seeing. The 'name' only makes sense when the exception has been caught in a block where name is defined. You're probably not in the correct block.

In general, if you're having class loading issues in tomcat, I'd turn up logging for org.apache.catalina.loader to debug rather than trying to use a debugger.